# Jquery effects from c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am wondering if there is any code, `dll` that allows developer to give effects to server control from code behind. I have a empty `div` and two `TextBox`es to select dates in kinda leave application form. When user select two values say 11-Oct-2014 and 14-Oct-2014 in those  `TextBox`es then I want to append `html table` markup to that empty `div` and it will consist number of `tr` equal to days of leave. I am doing it in `AJAX UpdatePanel` and and showing that on form. It's working fine but I want to know what if I want to use `Jquery` like `FadeIn` and `FadeOut` effect after appending `table` markup to `div`, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's totally possible, but you're much better off just including a js file that does it for you.

Comment: You can't do it in the code behind as that occurs on the server before anything actually reaches the browser. However there is nothing stopping you using JS to animate things once the response is returned to the browser.

Comment: @BenRobinson I should be agree with you, any alternative?

Comment: @BenRobinson server-side code can inject javscript into the page that does what is required.  It's laborious and painfully bad practice, but it will do what he's asking.  I speak from bitter experience :p

Comment: @Archer You mean adding jquery library in my page and creating script string and running it through `ScriptManager`'s `RegisterClientScript`, it will work? If so, I must give it a try :)

Comment: No - do not do it that way.  It's horrible.  You're much, much better off writing client-side javascript that you can simply include in the page, and have it handle events triggered when the table is modified.  I was just saying it's possible, but for something like this you should do it with client-side script.

Comment: @Archer I know you can, perhaps i wasn't clear but I was just trying to say you can only do it with JavaScript, however that JavaScript may be rendered to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very generic, but you can adapt it to suit...

http://jsfiddle.net/dv9a0ubw/1/

**html**

```
<button id="add-row">add a row</button>
<br />
<br />
<table id="my-table">
    <tr>
        <td>something 1</td>
        <td>something 2</td>
        <td>something 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
$("#my-table").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    $(this).find("tr:last").hide().fadeIn(2000);
});

$("#add-row").on("click", function() {
    var $row = $("<tr><td>new 1</td><td>new 2</td><td>new 3</td></tr>");
    $("#my-table").append($row);
});
```

As you can see, the button simply adds a row and that's it.  The animation is applied by the event handler detecting a change in the table.  You can retro-fit this to any table by modifying the table selector, using a class if you mean to use it in multiple instances.